# Are these buttons solely for cosmetic purposes?

Tags: surgeon-simulator

In Surgeon Simulator for iOS, there are these green, yellow, and red buttons on a machine. This is what it looks like:

[image]

When I press them, the only thing I notice them doing is turning on and off (as in the buttons themselves). Is there a combination of colors that I need to press to unlock something or are they just there to play around with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are purely cosmetic.  They serve no other function than eye candy.